# Shows remote connection corectly but error: failed to push some refs error

Tags: git, github

I am trying to set up git and did some test, by adding a Remote connection as below.

## On the loal machine

```
git init
```

Initialized empty Git repository in C:/CRMNext/Git/speech_to_text_auto_2/.git/

```
git status
```

On branch master

No commits yet

Untracked files:
  (use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)
        README.md.txt

```
git add .

git status
```

On branch master

No commits yet

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached ..." to unstage)
        new file:   README.md.txt

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:Sarrae1406/speech_to_text_auto_2.git

git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:Sarrae1406/speech_to_text_auto_2.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:Sarrae1406/speech_to_text_auto_2.git (push)

git push origin master
error: src refspec master does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:Sarrae1406/speech_to_text_auto_2.git'
```

Whats missing to complete a push to Github ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+error%3A+src+refspec+master+does+not+match+any

Comment: This is your problem: "*On branch master/No commits yet*".